# My React Native App Had started in dark mode by default

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

When I created a new fresh React Native App, it started with dark mode. Previously my react native app would start with light/white background. I don't know how to disable the mode. Please help me to disable the dark mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest React Native CLI app template uses the `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar` Android theme (set in the AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml), which adds some automatic dark mode behavior based on a number of conditions. The  Android dev documentation is a good place to start to learn about this. You can also change the theme of course if you want different behavior.